# Solidity - ecrecover function is returning an incorrect address than the expected one

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to sign a message and verify it later. But while verifying,
the returned address from the ecrecover is very odd and not matching with any of the accounts I am using.

**Solidity Code:-**

```
    library CryptoSuite { function splitSignature(bytes memory sig) internal pure returns(uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) {
        require(sig.length == 65);
 
        assembly{
            // first 32bytes
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
 
            // next 32bytes
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
 
            // last 32bytes
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig,96)))
        }
        return (v, r, s);
    }
    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes memory sig) internal pure returns (address) {
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(sig);
        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);   //recovers the value of the person who signed this
       }
    }

       function isMatchingSignature(bytes32 message, uint id, address issuer) public view returns (address) {
       Certificate memory cert = certificates[id];
       require(cert.issuer.id == issuer);
       
       address recoveredSigner = CryptoSuite.recoverSigner(message, cert.signature);
       return recoveredSigner == cert.issuer.id;
   }
```

**Java Script Code**

```
    it('should verify that the certificate signature matches the issuer', async () => {
    const {inspector, manufacturerA} = this.defaultEntities;
    const vaccineBatchId = 0;
    const message = `Inspector(${inspector.id}) has certified vaccine batch #${vaccineBatchId} for Manufacturer (${manufacturerA.id}).`;
    
    //const message = `Inspector has certified vaccine batch for Manufacturer (${manufacturerA.id}).`;
   
    const certificate = await this.coldChainInstance.certificates.call(0);
    console.log(certificate);
 
    const signerMatches = await this.coldChainInstance.isMatchingSignature(
      this.web3.utils.keccak256(message),
      certificate.id,
      inspector.id,
      { from : this.owner }
    );
    console.log(signerMatches);
    assert.equal(signerMatches, true, "can't verify");
  });
```

Comment: You may want to ask these questions in this dedicated forum . https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you!! Yes, I have posted the same question in there as well with full Solidity and .JS code. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/132911/solidity-ecrecover-function-is-returning-an-incorrect-address-than-the-expecte